# How to change the name of the image that is being uploaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the name of the image in file uploader using jquery.is there any chance to do that please let me know.I am struggling with that.

I am using the regular html file uploader

Thanks,
Sravz

Comment: when you receive the file and save it on the server you can call what ever you want.. !?

Comment: Why not handle naming server side? I don't think client side this is possible.

Comment: Presumably you are using some kind of server-side script (PHP perhaps) to actually process the file upload?

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to change what is displayed in the file field after you have chosen a file. You can change the style or hide the text altogether though.

If you need to rename the file you will have to do it using whatever server side language you are using when the file is actually uploaded.